# VSCode: Blazor Server, Intellisense problems

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server website opened in VSCode, And I installed C# (Omnisharp), Razor+, Html Css Support, Extensions installed. I also have Radzen Blazor, AntDesign and Blazor-ApexCharts Packages intalled.

But ant design and apex charts have no intellisense and Radzen has a limited intellisense, for example RadzenDataGrid tag has no intellisense but RadzenButton tag has.

My second problem is intellisense for attributes. since it is only sorted by abc that is not useful for Blazor dev, I installed syncfusion Blazor VSCode Extensions but it has no effect on component attributes.

How to make intellisense work for razor third party components and for components attributes correctly?

Comment: have you ever found solution for this? I have the same issue with Mudblazor. General html attributes intellisense working but Mudblazor properties intellisense doesnt